# What is wrong with my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Here is the exercise I'm doing : http://www.codecademy.com/courses/building-an-address-book/0/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#

```
Here is my code:

var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

// printPerson added here
function printPerson(person){
    console.log(firstName);
    console.log(lastName);
};

function printPerson(){
        console.log(contacts[0]);
}
function printPerson(){
        console.log(contacts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Also add details on my mistake in code . I want to learn from my mistakes .

Comment: you mean other than the fact that you have three functions with the same name?

Comment: And what actully the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

// printPerson added here
function printPerson(person){
    console.log(person.firstName + " "+ person.lastName);   
}

printPerson(contacts[0]);
printPerson(contacts[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to execute printPerson for the last two parts of the code and not recreate the function

```
function printPerson(person){
    console.log(person.firstName);
    console.log(person.lastName);
};

printPerson(contacts[0]);
printPerson(contacts[1]);
```

Comment: Where are `firstName` and `lastName` defined?

Comment: @cookiemonster, whoops forgot to prepend `person.`

Answer (score 0):

where you've written

```
function printPerson(){
        console.log(contacts[0]);
    }
function printPerson(){
        console.log(contacts[1]);
    }
```

You should have written

```
printPerson(contacts[0]);
printPerson(contacts[1]);
```

Otherwise you're just redefining the functions instead of calling them.